# Chrome Extension - get current tab url and re-open it (in a new tab) not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to re-open the current site in a new tab when clicking on the icon of my extension in Chrome. Instead of re-opening the same site it opens a new empty tab with NO URL. So if I'm on Twitter.com it opens a new chrome start page instead of Twitter.com

The code below is in background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(openTabs);
function openTabs(){
    var currentURL;

    chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'windowId': 
chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT},
    function(tabs){
        getCurrentURL(tabs[0].url);
    });

    function getCurrentURL(tab){
        currentURL = tab;
    }

chrome.tabs.create({ url: currentURL });
}
```

Comment: Move `chrome.tabs.create` inside `chrome.tabs.query` callback. This callback is asynchronous, meaning that currently `chrome.tabs.create` gets called before `currentURL` variable is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, moving chrome.tabs.create inside chrome.tabs.query solved it.

> Move chrome.tabs.create inside chrome.tabs.query callback. This callback is asynchronous, meaning that currently chrome.tabs.create gets called before currentURL variable is updated. –